# vue-cli-service build : Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js)

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I am trying to build a vue.js spa in a docker environment but the "vue-cli-service build" command keeps failing. This is kinda frustrating because building for production without docker is working. Also I am able to successfully run "vue-cli-service serve" in my docker environment.

I am pretty new to Docker and I don't know where to start from.

Here's the dockerfile :

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
    apache2 curl nano git-all

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get install supervisor -y
ADD config/front-spa/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
ADD config/front-spa/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
ADD config/front-spa/start.sh /home/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/start.sh
```

Here's my docker-composer.yml :

```yaml
version: "3.1"

services: 

    front-spa:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "xxxx:xxxx"
            - "xxxx:xxxx"
        environment: 
            GIT_URL: https://[GIT_USER]:[GIT_PASS]@bitbucket.org/[...].git
            SUPERVISOR_USER: [SUPERVISOR_USER]
            SUPERVISOR_PASS: [SUPERVISOR_PASS]
            BASE_URL: http://127.0.0.1:xxxx
            BASE_URL_API: http:127.0.0.1:xxxx
        entrypoint: ./home/start.sh
```

Here's the entrypoint start.sh :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "s|SUPERVISOR_USER|${SUPERVISOR_USER}|g" /etc/supervisord.conf
sed -i "s|SUPERVISOR_PASS|${SUPERVISOR_PASS}|g" /etc/supervisord.conf

mkdir /var/www/site
cd /var/www/site
git clone ${GIT_URL} .

sed -i "s|http://localhost:5000|${BASE_URL_API}|g" /var/www/site/src/api.js
sed -i "s|BASE_URL|${BASE_URL_API}|g" /var/www/site/public/index.html

npm i
npm run build

/usr/bin/supervisord --configuration=/etc/supervisord.conf
```

And finally the stack trace :

```
-  Building for production...
front-spa_1  |  ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors12:56:09 PM
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   Error: Child compilation failed:
front-spa_1  |   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
front-spa_1  |   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Function
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - lodash.js:14870
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14870:16
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - lodash.js:473 apply
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[lodash]/lodash.js:473:27
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - lodash.js:15254
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[lodash]/lodash.js:15254:16
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - lodash.js:475 apply
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[lodash]/lodash.js:475:27
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - lodash.js:6563
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[lodash]/lodash.js:6563:16
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - lodash.js:14869 Function.template
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14869:20
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - compiler.js:79
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Compiler.js:343
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Compiler.js:681
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Compiler.js:678
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Compilation.js:1423
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - Compilation.js:1414
front-spa_1  |     [site]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |
front-spa_1  |   - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
front-spa_1  |     internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
```

Thanks in advance !